# How to rid onself of the locales hint from the Guix package manager

Tags: guix

Every time I run the package manager Guix on a foreign distro I'm greeted with the following "hint":

> hint: Consider installing the `glibc-utf8-locales' or` glibc-locales'
> package and defining `GUIX_LOCPATH', along these lines:
>
> ```
>  guix install glibc-utf8-locales
>  export GUIX_LOCPATH="$HOME/.guix-profile/lib/locale"
> ```
>
> See the "Application Setup" section in the manual, for more info.

Only problem is, I've already got `glibc-utf8-locales` installed and `GUIX_LOCPATH` is set to the above mentioned path.

```
$ guix package --list-installed
glibc-utf8-locales  2.31    out /gnu/store/rgydar9dfvflqqz2irgh7njj34amaxc6-glibc-utf8-locales-2.31
$ echo $GUIX_LOCPATH
/home/rovanion/.guix-profile/lib/locale
$ ll ~/.guix-profile/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 2 root root 71 jan  1  1970 /home/rovanion/.guix-profile/lib -> /gnu/store/rgydar9dfvflqqz2irgh7njj34amaxc6-glibc-utf8-locales-2.31/lib/
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be lying name combined with me not using one of the following locales:

```
de_DE.utf8  de_DE.UTF-8  el_GR.utf8  el_GR.UTF-8  en_US.utf8  en_US.UTF-8  fr_FR.utf8  fr_FR.UTF-8  tr_TR.utf8  tr_TR.UTF-8
```

Turns out that the package `glibc-utf8-locales` does not contain all utf8 locales but only a select few, as the package description notes:

```
This package provides a small sample of UTF-8 locales mostly useful in test environments.
```

Given that I use use a swedish locale

```
$ env | grep LC
LC_ADDRESS=sv_SE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sv_SE.UTF-8
...
```

which was not present in this small selection of locales, the solution to my problem was to install `glibc-locales` which does contain all available locales.

Comment: You can easily define packages "on the fly" and immediately install them. Example: `guix package -e '((@ (gnu packages base) make-glibc-utf8-locales) (@ (gnu packages base) glibc) #:locales (list "en_US" "ru_RU") #:name "glibc-utf8-locales-en-ru")'`